# How can I update Text column that represents JSON in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

I have a column (TEXT) which stores json text. I need to update the data.

I am using [json_replace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-replace) but I didn't manage to do it and get errors.

`JSON_REPLACE(SELECT text_column from payment_options WHERE id=1, '$.card_number', 'update to this')`

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c5V6SULjehVfJ5MF3diKbL/0)

Comment: If you want to use JSON functions you'll need to use a JSON column, not a TEXT column. Why don't you just unpack the data into proper columns and make life easy?

Comment: Unfortunately, this column cannot change to JSON.

Comment: Try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7d7c276b107f4d26cf650dc985fef7a9).

Comment: @wchiquito perfect! That worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. Wrap your "SELECT" statement in a parenthesis so that '$.card_number' etc. are not mistakenly used as another "WHERE" clause.

```
SELECT JSON_REPLACE((SELECT text_column from payment_options WHERE id=1), '$.card_number', 'update to this')
```

If you want to update the underlying JSON data, you can use this

```
UPDATE `payment_options`
SET `text_column` = JSON_REPLACE(text_column, '$.card_number', 'update to this')
WHERE `id`=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON_SET function as well.

Function signature is the same.

JSON_SET() replaces existing values and adds nonexisting values.

```
JSON_SET() replaces existing values and adds nonexisting values.
JSON_INSERT() inserts values without replacing existing values.
JSON_REPLACE() replaces only existing values.
```